# How to ignore to appending schema name with entity or view in spring boot 3.0.0

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have just migrated an application from spring boot 2.x to Spring Boot 3.0, and then schema name started adding in entity at run time. I want to ignore appending schema name from entity. How can I igore it ?

```php
@Table(name = "employeee")
```

But at run time it is executing `mydb.employeee`. just I want to ignore appending mydb.

Comment: Does it cause an exception?

Comment: That is most likely not done by Spring Data JPA but by the JPA implementation. Probably Hibernate, maybe EclipseLink. Please tag the JPA implementation you are using.

Comment: I am using two schema that's the reason it cause an exception.

Answer (score 0):

To ignore the appending schema name with entity,  you can set the spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema in application.properties

Comment: This in not working in multi tenancy case as we have two database some of the entity is in one db and some of them in another db.

Comment: Pls help out to fix this problem.